# genisoimage script cannot burn bigger than 4GB but less than 4.5GB file?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, iso

I found it strange after running the following script file.

```
#! /bin/sh
# krhowto_4
# Path to partition you will work on
PFAD="/media/sda1"
START=$(date +'%s')
# Disable screensaver
xscreensaver-command -exit
# Build new inital RAM-disk
cd $PFAD/knx/minirt/minirtdir/
find . | cpio -oH newc | gzip -9 > ../minirt.gz
cp $PFAD/knx/minirt/minirt.gz $PFAD/knx/master/boot/isolinux/
# Make the big  compressed filesystem KNOPPIX
genisoimage -input-charset ISO-8859-15 -R -l -D -V KNOPPIX_FS -quiet \
  -no-split-symlink-components -no-split-symlink-fields \
  -hide-rr-moved -cache-inodes $PFAD/knx/source/KNOPPIX \
  | /usr/sbin/create_compressed_fs -q -B 65536 -t 8 -L 9 \
  -f $PFAD/knx/isotemp - $PFAD/knx/master/KNOPPIX/KNOPPIX
# Update the file hashes used by the "testcd" boot option
cd $PFAD/knx/master ; find -type f -not -name \
  sha1sums -not -name boot.cat -not \
  -name isolinux.bin -exec sha1sum '{}' \; > KNOPPIX/sha1sums
# Create new Knoppix ISO
genisoimage -l -r -J -V "KNOPPIX" \
  -b boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table -c boot/isolinux/boot.cat \
  -o $PFAD/knx/remastered.iso $PFAD/knx/master
# Enable screensaver
su knoppix -c "xscreensaver -nosplash &"
echo -e "\nFinished! Used time: $(expr $(expr $(date +'%s') - $START) / 60) min. \
  and $(expr $(expr $(date +'%s') - $START) % 60) sec. \
  \n\nThe new ISO is stored in '$PFAD/knx/remastered.iso' "
```

When the script file run at

```
genisoimage -l -r -J -V "KNOPPIX" \
  -b boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table -c boot/isolinux/boot.cat \
  -o $PFAD/knx/remastered.iso $PFAD/knx/master
```

It display the following error message:

```
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8
File /media/sda1/knx/master/KNOPPIX/KNOPPIX is larger than 4GiB-1.
-allow-limited-size was not specified. There is no way to represent this file size. Aborting.
```

Although I tried with the CD version, it works. but for the DVD version, it failed to generate a ISO file.

Some website recommend that I used `mkisofs` with the parameters `-iso-level 3` so that there will be no restriction to the size but are there `genisoimage` equivalent command?

Thus, would appreciate if anyone can enlighten me how I can use `genisoimage` to create the DVD as I suspect that the following command that I have come out with might not work.

```
genisoimage -input-charset ISO-8859-15 -l -r -J -V "KNOPPIX" \
  -b boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 \
      -iso-level 3 \
  -boot-info-table -c boot/isolinux/boot.cat \
  -o $PFAD/knx/remastered.iso $PFAD/knx/master
```

Added Info: The partition of /media/sda1/ is `ext2`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-allow-limited-size` flag as the error message suggested?

Comment: @janos, yes, I tried the `-allow-limited-size` flag, the ISO is able to generated but it cannot run as it display `Compressed KNOPPIX image is broken: /mnt-system/KNOPPIX/KNOPPIX` and also `cloop: final offset wrong`

Answer (score 15):

`mkisofs -allow-limited-size -l -J -r -iso-level 3 -o <output.iso> <source file or directory>`

`genisoimage -allow-limited-size -l -J -r -iso-level 3 -o <output.iso> <source file or directory>`

Either one of these commands will generate an ISO that is bigger than 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command (-iso-level 3 resolve issue):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\cdrtools\mkisofs.exe" -r -R -J -l -iso-level 3 -o "C:\temp\image-file.iso" "C:\files_for_iso"
```

Answer (score -7):

reduce the linux size then you can make an iso.
here is the manuel remove code :(run after the chroot)
find /etc/usr/share/doc -depth -type f ! -name copyright | xargs rm || true

Comment: Imagine you have a 20Gb folder. There is NO way to reduce it's size so that I can be lower than 4Gb so this is not an answer